# Intellij idea javascript recognition in script tag where type isn't "text/javascript"

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I use MathJax javascript library. When I change MathJax config I have a problem because he is actually javascript code but his type is "text/x-mathjax-config" and Intellij Idea don't recognize him as code.

Can I add extra types to Intellij Idea configuration for javascript support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JetBrains support team gave me [answer](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5506225#5506225):

1. Settings / Language Injections.
2. Add XML tag injection.
3. In its properties:

   - Language ID: JavaScript (or any you like).
   - XML Tag local name: script.
   - XPath condition: @type="text/x-mathjax-config"

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out how to do this in PhpStorm / Webstorm for Paperscript ("text/paperscript") and finally found this, works great!

Comment: For me xpath condition is not active... Can't set any value here

Comment: @let4be from IDEA help: _For the field to be active, the XPathView + XSLT Support plugin must be enabled._

Comment: It seems that plugin is outdated and incompatible with current versions of IntelliJ