# How do I fix the comment syntax used inside script tags?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

While editing an HTML file in IntelliJ IDEA, when I use Command-/ to comment a line of JavaScript inside a script tag, the comment that is created has a curly brace & hash instead of a slash and asterisk:

```
<script>
{# this is a comment #} 
</script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script>
// this is a comment 
</script>
```

How can I determine why IntelliJ is using this comment format and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: It's because of your file type. You are probably in some templating file extension (handlebars?) so its defaulting to the comment syntax for that file. You can probably just change it to JavaScript temporarily or you can avoid using inline scripts, and simply move your script to its own separate js file.

Comment: Thanks @aug. Can you tell me how I would change it to JavaScript?

(I'm using script tags inside Polymer HTML components and it's nice to keep the code close to the HTML, otherwise I would put them in a JS file.)

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683870/intellij-idea-javascript-recognition-in-script-tag-where-type-isnt-text-javasc) question has what you are looking for.

Comment: Darn, that doesn't seem to be fixing it. I tried removing all the injections except the built-in entries for CSS & JavaScript, and tried creating a new JavaScript entry by following the instructions in the link you gave. I guess I'll post a question to the IntelliJ support site. Thanks very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had Jinja2 selected as a Python template language in Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Python Template Languages. I changed the template language there to None and now Command-/ seems to be working normally again.